# Sounddevice exit code 0

Tags: python, scipy, device, exit, python-sounddevice

I am working on a genre identification project and trying to utilize sounddevice to input the audio. I have attempted using sample code from their website as well as stack overflow but am unable to get the codes to run without finishing with exit code 0. I've seen where people have said this is a device identification issue but even with declaring the input/output im am still not recording any audio. 
Here is the code below

```
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
sd.default.device = 1,3;
fs = 44100 #sample rate
duration = 5 

myrecording = sd.rec(int(duration*fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
sd.wait()
write('output.wav,fs myrecording)
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows 10, im using Pycharm to write my code

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Are you certain your [default device](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.7/#sounddevice.default) should be specified as `1,3`?, these may be the incorrect input/output channels - you can print the `sd.DeviceList` [to find out more info about your actual devices](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.7/#sounddevice.DeviceList).
2. When you call `sd.rec(..., channels=2)` are you sure that your input device has 2 channels? This isn't always the case (i.e. a normal microphone is a single channel unless you are using some sort of audio interface) tip -> you can use [query_channels()](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.7/#sounddevice.query_devices) to found out how many channels your device supports
3. I presume that the `write('output.wav,fs myrecording)` was just a typo? You should make sure its `write('output.wav',fs myrecording)`

Personally in my experience (and preference) I always had more success with [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-blocking-mode-audio-i-o) and would usually recommend it for desktop audio I/O with Python!